# How do I write a Python Selenium test script that contains more than one test case?

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium

I am working on a Selenium Webdriver script in Python which only partially does what I want it to. I want it to run through a set of test cases, each in its own method in the class. So in the case of my script here, I want it to test the discount form (**test_add_discount**) then test the add unit form (**test_add_unit_type**).

Each time I run it, all I get is the first one, then it closes with the message;

> Ran 1 test in 12.948s

If I run it verbose with -v parameter, I still don't see any reference to the second test case at all.

Here is my script;

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import unittest, time, re

class AdminTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "http://mysite.local"

    def test_discount_test_case(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url + "/admin/login")
        driver.find_element_by_id("username").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys("admin")
        driver.find_element_by_id("password").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys("p@ssw0rd")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']").click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[4]/a/span").click()
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("Add Discount").click()
        driver.find_element_by_name("title").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_name("title").send_keys("Selenium Test Discount")
        driver.find_element_by_name("body").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_name("body").send_keys("Test discount text")
        driver.find_element_by_name("start_date").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_name("start_date").send_keys("01/01/2014")
        driver.find_element_by_name("end_date").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_name("end_date").send_keys("01/03/2014")
        driver.find_element_by_name("discount_percentage").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_name("discount_percentage").send_keys("33")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']").click()

    def test_add_unit_type(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url + "/maxsys/unit_types")
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("Add Unit type").click()
        driver.find_element_by_name("title").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_name("title").send_keys("Selenium Test Unit Type")
        driver.find_element_by_name("height").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_name("height").send_keys("22.5")
        driver.find_element_by_name("width").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_name("width").send_keys("Non-numeric")
        driver.find_element_by_name("depth").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_name("depth").send_keys("Test discount text")
        driver.find_element_by_name("body").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_name("body").send_keys("unit type description")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']").click()


    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException, e: return False
        return True

    def is_alert_present(self):
        try: self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        except NoAlertPresentException, e: return False
        return True

    def close_alert_and_get_its_text(self):
        try:
            alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
            alert_text = alert.text
            if self.accept_next_alert:
                alert.accept()
            else:
                alert.dismiss()
            return alert_text
        finally: self.accept_next_alert = True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: I notice that you don't have a `teardown()` method, could that be the problem? I'm guessing as I have never seen the issue you have here. All of your test case methods have 'test' in their name so they should be found.

Comment: I did have a tearDown() but it only ran the first test with that in place too. Are you saying that my approach is correct here then?

Comment: For all of my Webdriver tests I do something similar, I do use a base class that has the `setup` and `teardown` which each test class inherits from but I don't think that would make the difference. 
As ever with Python, maybe check your indents? EDIT: Just seen your answer, indents it was! Definitely set whatever your editor is to spaces, saves a lot of headaches like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it turns out my code is fine. The problem was Python's indenting rules. The indents in the second test case were tabs not spaces. I have now set my editor to replace tab characters with 4 spaces and it all runs as expected.

Pretty infuriating and worse than that, invisible to the human eye. However, when I type swear words into the internet about Python's indenting, I am told that I will learn to love it eventually, so I am trying to keep an open mind.

To catch this, I have just learned about the **-t** parameter when invoking a python script from command line, which will give warnings about mixed space and tab characters in Python 2.

Using **-tt** will escalate them from warnings to errors.